# Load XML-File -> Add items -> Reorder -> Write XML-File [PHP & SimpleXML]

Tags: php, simplexml

**SUMMARY**

1. Load existing XML-File
2. Add 2 items to every  child
3. Change order of  children
4. Write new XML-File

**DETAILED EXPLANATION**

This is a shortened sample of the Source-XML-File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<warehouse>
  <inventory>
    <name>Name 1</name>
    <markers>
     <marker>red</marker>
     <marker>yellow</marker>
     <marker>green</marker>
   </markers>
   (...)
  </inventory>
  <inventory>
    <name>Name 2</name>
    <markers>
     <marker>blue</marker>
     <marker>pink</marker>
     <marker>brown</marker>
   </markers>
   (...)
  </inventory>
  <inventory>
    <name>Name 3</name>
    <markers>
     <marker>black</marker>
     <marker>white</marker>
     <marker>marron</marker>
   </markers>
   (...)
  </inventory>
</warehouse>
```

**1. Load existing XML-File**

Load the XML-File into a variable.

```
$source_xmlfile = "source.xml";
$source_xml_file_contents = simplexml_load_file($source_xmlfile);
```

**2. Add 2 items to every  child**

Add 2 children to the first inventory with name and value.

```
$source_xml_file_contents->warehouse->inventory[0]->addChild("new1", "0.12345");
$source_xml_file_contents->warehouse->inventory[0]->addChild("new2", "17");
```

**3. Change order of  children**

This is the part that doesn't work for me, no matter what I tried.

My idea was the following:

```
$destination_xml_file_contents = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?><warehouse></warehouse>');
foreach($source_xml_file_contents->warehouse->inventory as $inventory){
  $destination_xml_file_contents->warehouse->addChild("inventory", $inventory);
}
```

The basic idea is that I take a child (<inventory>) out of <warehouse> and store in in a variable or maybe an array (which would be way better and easier) containing everything that <inventory> contains (including attributes and child nodes and so on).
After I have stored all <inventory> somewhere else I take a new XML and put the stored <inventory> in a new order into the new XML.

However it seems impossible to save a whole child into a variable (or an array) and add it to another XML later.

Since the order is not necessarily in order a simple sort wouldn't help me out here and since I wasn't able to get sorting to work I am at a loss here.

**4. Write new XML-File**

Save the new XML content to a new XML-File.

```
$new_xml_file = "destination.xml";
$destination_xml_file_contents->asXML($new_xml_file);
```

This is a shortened sample of the destination-XML-File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<warehouse>
  <inventory>
    <name>Name 2</name>
    <markers>
     <marker>blue</marker>
     <marker>pink</marker>
     </marker>brown</marker>
   </markers>
   (...)
   <new1>0.6789</new1>
   <new2>115</new2>
  </inventory>
  <inventory>
    <name>Name 1</name>
    <markers>
     <marker>red</marker>
     <marker>yellow</marker>
     </marker>green</marker>
   </markers>
   (...)
   <new1>0.4567</new1>
   <new2>4</new2>
  </inventory>
  <inventory>
    <name>Name 3</name>
    <markers>
     <marker>black</marker>
     <marker>white</marker>
     </marker>marron</marker>
   </markers>
   (...)
   <new1>0.1234</new1>
   <new2>17</new2>
  </inventory>
</warehouse>
```

Can someone help me to figure out how to make this work?

Right now I'm resorting to parse the whole XML-File and rewrite it line by line with string since SimpleXML doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You will be better off trying to use the DOMDocument API as it allows you to order items and copy nested data which SimpleXML doesn't.

Comment: I've already looked at DOMDocument, but so far I wasn't able to accomplish anything.

Comment: I am trying to get it working with DOMDocument, but apparently PHP and DOMDocument hate me.

Comment: I'm saving all <inventory> like this `$all_inventory = $source_xml_contents->getElementsByTagName("inventory");`

Comment: But so far I'm not able to read out the Name, save all <inventory> in an array, add child nodes to them, put them one by one into a new DOMDocument. Why does it always have to be so complicated to do simple tasks?

Comment: I have to go out for an hour or two, I will work on an answer when I get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things which I'm not sure about, but hopefully this code will show the principle of copying the nodes from one document to another (and adding content) using DOMDocument.  I've added comments to the code to help, if there is anything you are unsure about, then let me know.

```
$inFile = "data.xml";
$input = new DOMDocument();
$input->load($inFile);

$all_inventory = $input->getElementsByTagName("inventory");
// Add new content to each item
foreach ( $all_inventory as $inventory )    {
    $inventory->appendChild ( $input->createElement("new1", "0.12345"));
    $inventory->appendChild ( $input->createElement("new2", "17"));
}

$outFile = "out.xml";
$output = new DOMDocument();
// Create base document for destination
$output->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?><warehouse />');
// Get the root element as we will be adding content to this
$outputRoot = $output->documentElement;
foreach ( $all_inventory as $inventory )    {
    // Copy the element from the input document to the output document
    // Note this does not add it anywhere, just makes it available
    // The true option says make a deep copy
    $import = $output->importNode($inventory, true);
    // Add the newly imported node to the output document root
    $outputRoot->appendChild($import);
}
$output->save($outFile);
```

The output is almost just a copy of the input document with the extra data.  You could in the second `foreach()` loop add some logic to order the output elements in some other format, which I'm not sure what that is.

Also note there is a minor XML flaw in your document...

```
</marker>green</marker>
```

Comment: With a little modification I was finally able to get things going and now it works like a charm. Thank you for your work and the great explanation. I fixed the minor XML flaw in the original post. It is a mockup of my real XML and copy and paste got the best of me ;)